# False positive from assertThat on ArgumentCaptor.getValue() when changing value attribute after call on verified method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a load method and a save method in a DAO and a domain class. In my application I load a domain object, update attribute values and save the object again. I wrote this test for the app:

```
import ...

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyAppTest
{
    @Mock
    private MyDao myDao;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyApp myApp;

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod(){
        // given
        MyDomainClass myObj = new MyDomainClass();
        when(myDao.load(anyInt())).thenReturn(myObj);

        // when
        myApp.myMethod();

        // then
        ArgumentCaptor<MyDomainClass> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyDomainClass.class);
        verify(myDao).save(argumentCaptor.capture());
        assertThat(argumentCaptor.getValue().myInt, is(1));
    }
}
```

The test passes although the logic contains a bug:

```
public class MyApp
{
    private MyDao myDao = new MyDao();

    public void myMethod(){
        MyDomainClass myObj = myDao.load(0);
        myDao.save(myObj);
        System.out.println("Saved myObj with myInt=" + myObj.myInt); // myInt=0
        myObj.myInt = 1;
    }
}
```

My question is if anyone else experienced this, and what (junit) test strategy would expose the bug.

**EDIT:** In response to the first suggested solution, I replaced the argument captor like so:

```
...
@Test
public void testMyMethod(){
...
        MyDomainClass expected = new MyDomainClass();
        expected.myInt = 1;
        verify(myDao).save(eq(expected));
}
```

and the test still passes. The reason is the same: by the time `verify` is invoked, the value of myInt is `1` in both instances. I'm trying to verify that `save` was invoked with `myInt` of `myObj` set to `0`, i.e. this test should fail.

My question was also if there is a general thing, e.g. a different test strategy that I should consider. Are ArgumentCaptors a bad choice in some cases? I know I could write an integration test instead, but imo this should be testable in a unit test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time this is invoked ...

```
assertThat(argumentCaptor.getValue().myInt, is(1));
```

... the value of `myInt` **is** `1` since it is set to that value inside `myApp.myMethod();` which is invoked **before** the verification.

**Using an `Answer`**

If you want to assert against the state of `MyDomainClass` *as it was* when `myDao.save()` was invoked then you'll need to capture that state via an answer in the 'when' stage.

Since Mockito records a reference to the `MyDomainClass` instance passed to `myDao.save()` (rather than a copy of it) you could use an `Answer` to record your own copy and then assert against that copy.

For example:

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod(){
    // given
    MyDomainClass myObj = new MyDomainClass();
    when(myDao.load(anyInt())).thenReturn(myObj);

    AtomicReference<MyDomainClass> actualSavedInstance = new AtomicReference<>();

    doAnswer(invocation -> {
        MyDomainClass supplied = (MyDomainClass) invocation.getArguments()[0];

        // copy/clone state from supplied - which represents the instance passed to save - into a separate
        // instance which can be used for an assertion
        MyDomainClass actual = new MyDomainClass();
        actual.myInt = supplied.myInt;
        actualSavedInstance.set(actual);
        return null;
    }).when(myDao).save(myObj);

    // when
    myApp.myMethod();

    assertThat(actualSavedInstance.get().myInt, is(0));
}
```

**An Alternative**

An alternative to this might be to delegate the 'post update increment' within `MyDao.save()` to a separate actor and then mock that actor and verify it.

For example, change `MyApp` as follows:

```
public void myMethod(){
    MyDomainClass myObj = myDao.load(0);
    myDao.save(myObj);
    System.out.println("Saved myObj with myInt=" + myObj.myInt); // myInt=0

    // the handler will do this: myObj.myInt = 1;
    postSaveHandler.handle(myObj);
}
```

And then implement the test like so:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyAppTest
{
    @Mock
    private MyDao myDao;
    @Mock
    private PostSaveHandler postSaveHandler;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyApp myApp;

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod(){
        // given
        MyDomainClass myObj = new MyDomainClass();
        when(myDao.load(anyInt())).thenReturn(myObj);

        // when
        myApp.myMethod();

        ArgumentCaptor<MyDomainClass> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyDomainClass.class);
        verify(myDao).save(argumentCaptor.capture());
        assertThat(argumentCaptor.getValue().myInt, is(0));

        verify(postSaveHandler).handle(myObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the opportunity to try this, please see my update.

Comment: Apologies, I had thought that the verify would test `eq()` against the state it captured on invocation. I have now updated the answer to show use of `doAnswer` to capture that state exactly as it was when `myDao.save` is invoked. This is functional and I _think_ it is the only way - when using Mockito - to test the code you showed.

Comment: I've added an alternative implementation which allows you original test to pass without the false positive.

Comment: Yes, that is what I asked, thanks. It seems to be generally better to use `Answer`s when verifying mutable method arguments.